# Removing Last Comma

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have a string like:

> SELECT  Sparte_id, Registernummer, Gesellschaft_ID, pk_id, Gesellschaft_Name, gesellschaft_crm,

Now I want to remove the last ,(comma) from the string. There are one, two, or three spaces after the last comma.

I am thinking of removing the last few letters. How could I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [string.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx):

```
var result = query.TrimEnd(',', ' ', '\n');
```

Comment: SELECT Sparte_id, Registernummer, Gesellschaft_ID, pk_id, Gesellschaft_Name, gesellschaft_crm,\n


Sorry. My string is this.
This is not working for me. This is as it was.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion - it looks like you're trying to build list of fields (comma separated) - try using:

```
var fields = new List<string>();
var csv = fields.Aggregate((x,y) => x + ";" + y);
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `String.Join(',', fields)`